# Show input field based on ng-if condition

Tags: html, angularjs, radio-button, angular-ngmodel, angular-ng-if

I've two radio buttons **VAT & CST** and one input field. If I select VAT the input field should appear and if I select input field should be hidden. How to do it in angularJS. Thank You!

Here is my code

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="vat" name="source" value="VAT"> VAT
<input type="radio" name="source" value="CST"> CST

<input type="number" ng-if="vat" placeholder="Gunny VAT">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-model`.

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="flag" name="source" value="VAT"> VAT
<input type="radio" ng-model="flag" name="source" value="CST"> CST

<input type="number" ng-if="flag == 'VAT'" placeholder="Gunny VAT">
```

FYI, you can also use `ng-show` `ng-hide` for the same.

Comment: Cool, you were fast

Comment: `ng-model="flag"` is working fine. if I use `ng-model="flag.selected"` it is not working

Comment: Firstly you need to declare that in your controller like `$scope.flag = {selected : {}}`

Comment: I'm not gonna use any controller. I'm just using it in the form.

Comment: @e-Designary : See I've updated my answer for flag :)
Still in Angular I would recommend to use ng-model as object.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <input type="radio" ng-model="selected" name="source" value="VAT"> VAT
<input type="radio" ng-model="selected" name="source" value="CST"> CST
<input type="number" ng-if="selected == 'VAT'" placeholder="Gunny VAT">
</div>
</body>
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/y0Hq4STsh2fmt8D0YsM8?p=preview)